# Render nested string inside of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render a dynamic list of fields from a JSON file.
Some fields have to go through this `accountFieldMap` object I created for key renaming purposes.

For example it finds the key `userFirstName1` from the JSON and renders the value of it as `firstName` at the component.

```
  const accountFieldMap = {
    firstName: "userFirstName1",
    lastName: "userLastName1",
    ID: "userID",
    location: `userLocation.city`,
  };
```

The only issue is with the `location` field.
How can I let JavaScript know that it should render that `city` nested field and show it as `location`?

Comment: does lodash get not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `location.city` is a path to some value in object.

There are some libraries for this like lodash, which have inbuilt functions that can resolve that, but if you want to do it in vanilla js, you can do it by splitting this string by dot and going through that array to get a value.

```
const getByPath = (path, obj) => {
  const splittedPath = path.split(".");
  return splittedPath.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      acc = obj[curr];
      return acc;
  }, obj)
}
```

So in this case if you have object like

```
const testObj = {
  location: {city: "Kyiv"},
  firstName: "Oleg"
}
```

It will return you "Kyiv" if you will pass into `getByPath` "location.city" as path. And it will also work in case if there is no nesting, so

```
getByPath("firstName", testObj)
```

will return you "Oleg"

Comment: If you don't want to write your own method for this use `lodash.get` from npm.

Comment: Thanks Oleg I tried your getByPath("userFirstName1", props?.account) but I received an Undefined error.  @matthiasgiger I also tried _.get("userFirstName1"). But it doesn't render the field (blank).

Comment: Yep, I forgot to handle undefined\null values, you can just put a little condition before split to check if path or obj in null\undefined. 
It doesn't mean to render any fields, its just to get a data from object

Answer (score 0):

you only have to map the array and create a new object;

```
import fileData from "../path/to/json";

const people = fileData.arrayName.map(person => ({
    firstName: person.userFirstName1,
    lastName: person.userLastName1,
    ID: person.userID,
    location: person.userLocation.city,
}));
```